# NUnit - assembly that reads and writes file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am unit testing an assembly that uses  File.WriteAllLines() and File.ReadAllText() to read and write persistent data.  When I run the unit test with the NUnit Gui the test fails with an unauthorizedAccessException.

The path that the file is attempting to read and write is being affected of course by the location of program execution.  Depending on if I run NUnit under Visual Studio or directly from the Nunit /bin folder, this is where the attempted read and write operation is taking place.

I have tried to run NUnit as administrator and have copied all of the assemblies directly to the NUnit /bin folder and the test still fails.

I do not want to directly set a path in the assembly.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why not skip testing the framework entirely, and just verify that the methods are called with the expected parameter values?

Comment: One good approach, is to use a memorystream and check For changes as it was a real file. Because what you might want to test is the logic of your algorithm, not the act of saving a file, I assume?

Comment: Unless you have to test some sort file locking/sharing mechanism, that was made by you, than I suppose it would require a lot of asserts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) to get a temporary file to write to.

Alternatively, you could use [`Assembly.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) to find out where your assembly is, and use that as the directory.

Comment: Thanks Jon,

We used Assembly.location.

Answer (score 4):

With NUnit 3 you should use TestContext to get either [TestDirectory](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html#testdirectory) or [WorkDirectory](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html#workdirectory).
Also there are [File Asserts](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/File-Assert.html) and [Directory Asserts](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Directory-Assert.html), which may help you write your tests in a more readable way.